# Cannot move to target thread (0x5bd982e1e8a0). In google colab

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, google-colaboratory

I am building a demo for an interactive colorizer through google colab. However, when I run the command to launch the software I get the following error:

> "QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x5bd982e1e8a0) is not the object's thread (0x5bd98889a460).
> Cannot move to target thread (0x5bd982e1e8a0)
>
> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
>
> Available platform plugins are: xcb, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl."

The application launches fine on my desktop but not in the google colab.

All of the code can be found here: [code](https://github.com/pmh9960/iColoriT/tree/main/iColoriT_demo)

I tried modifying the location of the QApplication creation from the middle of a loop to the beginning however, that did not change anything.